# React-native POST request body

Tags: android, post, fetch, react-native

I need to send a POST request to server without any body (login API). I'm trying to do it with fetch on Android and iOS but I'm getting error: **"method POST must have a request body"** 
Is there any option to disable it? I must send it via POST and without body. 
My code:

> ```
> fetch(url, {
>  method: 'POST',
>   headers: {
> 'Accept': 'application/json',
> 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
>   },
> })
> .then((response) => response.text())
> .then((responseText) => { console.log(responseText); })
> .catch((error) => { console.warn(error); });
> ```

Comment: Why can't you send a body with a whitespace character and just have the server ignore it?

Comment: And how would you send a username and so for your login?

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this issue while trying to send a POST over `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  My solution was to check for a body in my request handler and if the request is a POST and there is no body to specify `body: ''`  The request goes through with no problem now.  It seems like the fetch implementation in react-native is just looking for the `body` key.